# How long do the temporary HP gained from the Aberrant Dragonmark feat last?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, duration, temporary-hit-points

The [Aberrant Dragonmark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/aberrant-dragonmark) feat states (E:RftLW, p. 52; WGtE, p. 112):

> - [...] choose a 1st-level spell from the sorcerer spell list. You
>   learn that spell and can cast it through your mark. [...]
> - **When you cast the 1st-level spell through your mark, you can expend
>   one of your Hit Dice and roll it. If you roll an even number, you
>   gain a number of temporary hit points equal to the number rolled.**
>   [...]

How long do these temp HP last?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is answered on page 198 of the PHB or [here in the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TemporaryHitPoints):

> #### Temporary Hit Points
>
> ...
> Unless a feature that grants you temporary hit points has a duration, **they last until they're depleted or you finish a long rest.**